# How to get the timestamp from the latest event on the etherscan.io apis

Tags: events, etherscan, external-api

How to get the timestamp from the latest event on a contract using the etherscan.io api ?

I'm using the getLogs call this way:
https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=logs&action=getLogs&fromBlock=6572886&toBlock=latest&address=xxx&apikey=xxx

Seems you need to use the fromBlock=xxx toBlock=xxx arguments but I can't figure out a convenient way to know if an event happened in the last day for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blockchain doesn't have an understanding of "time", only "blocks"

In order to get close, your assumption is correct, you will need to estimate the average blocks per time period / hashrate, and query based on that